# Sending NDEF messages over NFC

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, android-beam

I am working on an android application and I would like to know how to get the event when a message is sent?

For the moment it sends and receives NDEF messages really well.

However I want to catch the event when data is SUCCESSFULLY sent, I mean when the user presses their screen to confirm the transfer.

Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can use the [onNdefPushComplete](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback.html#onNdefPushComplete%28android.nfc.NfcEvent%29) callback.

From the docs:

> Class Overview
>
> A callback to be invoked when the system successfully
>   delivers your NdefMessage to another device.

Comment: i try to implement it but it seems to not going into the callback :s